# Java NIO select() returns without selected keys - why?

Tags: java, select, nio

In writing some test code I have found that Selector.select() can return without Selector.selectedKeys() containing any keys to process. This is happening in a tight loop when I register an accept()ed channel with

```
SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT
```

as the operations of interest.

According to the docs, select() should return when:

1) There are channels that can be acted upon.

2) You explicitly call Selector.wakeup() - no keys are selected.

3) You explicitly Thread.interrupt() the thread doing the select() - no keys are selected.

If I get no keys after the select() I must be in cases (2) and (3). However, my code is not calling wakeup() or interrupt() to initiate these returns.

Any ideas as to what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: remove `OP_CONNECT` from the list of operations you are interested in for the accepted connection -- an accepted connection is already connected.

I managed to reproduce the issue, which might be exactly what's happening to you:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;


public class MyNioServer {
  public static void main(String[] params) throws Exception {
    final ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverChannel.configureBlocking(true);
    serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 12345));
    System.out.println("Listening for incoming connections");
    final SocketChannel clientChannel = serverChannel.accept();
    System.out.println("Accepted connection: " + clientChannel);


    final Selector selector = Selector.open();
    clientChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    final SelectionKey clientKey = clientChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
    System.out.println("Selecting...");
    System.out.println(selector.select());
    System.out.println(selector.selectedKeys().size());
    System.out.println(clientKey.readyOps());
  }
}
```

After the above server receives a connection, the very first `select()` on the connection exits without blocking and there are no keys with ready operations. I don't know why Java behaves in this way, but it appears many people get bitten by this behavior.

The outcome is the same on Sun's JVM 1.5.0_06 on Windows XP as well as Sun's JVM 1.5.0_05 and 1.4.2_04 on Linux 2.6.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is clearly an anomaly in the behaviour of select, but its easily solvable.

Comment: @FrankTaylor I don't know why a programming error should be considered `an anomaly in the behaviour of select'.

Answer (score 10):

The reason is that `OP_CONNECT` and `OP_WRITE` are the same thing under the hood, so you should never be registered for both simultaneously (ditto `OP_ACCEPT` and `OP_READ`), and you should never be registered for `OP_CONNECT` at all when the channel is already connected, as it is in this case, having been accepted.

And `OP_WRITE` is almost always ready, except when the socket send buffer in the kernel is full, so you should only register for that after you get a zero length write. So by registering the already connected channel for `OP_CONNECT,` you were really registering for `OP_WRITE,` which was ready, so `select()` got triggered.

Answer (score -1):

Upd: added client.finishConnect() as per [@user207421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421) suggestion

You should use `OP_CONNECT` when you connect to server, not when you are listening for incoming connections. Also make sure to configureBlocking **before** connect:

```
    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    SocketChannel serverChannel = SocketChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET);
    serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    serverChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5454));
    serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
    // event process cycle
    { 
        int count = selector.select();
        for (SelectionKey key : selector.selectedKeys()) {
            log.info("    {}", key.readyOps());
            if (key.isConnectable()) {
                boolean connected = client.finishConnect();
                log.info("Connection is ready: {}", connected);
                if (connected) {
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                }
            }
            if (key.isReadable()) {
                // read data here
            }
    }
```

Comment: If `isConnectable()` fires you need to call `finishConnect()` and check its return value. Your `log.info()` call is wrong as well. This code is not correct.