# sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport uses 100% CPU

Tags: java, nio

I'm developping a communication library based on NIO's non-blocking SocketChannels so I can use `select` to keep my thread low on CPU usage (and getting faster reaction time to other events).
`SocketChannel` are created externally to my thread and added to the list it handles, marking them as non-blocking and adding them to a `Selector` for READ operations (and WRITE when needed, but that does not happen in my problem).

I have a little Swing application for tests, running locally, that can be either a client or server: the client one connects to the server one and they can send each other messages. Pretty simple and works fine, excepts for the CPU which tops 100% (50% for each jvm) as soon as the connection is established between client and server.

Running `jvisualvm` shows me that `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run()` uses 98% of the application time, counting only 3 method calls!
A forced stack trace shows it's blocking on the `read` operation on a `FilteredInputStream`, on a `Socket`.

I'm a little puzzled as I don't use RMI (though I can understand NIO and RMI can share the "transport" code part). I have seen a few similar questions but each were specifically using RMI, which I'm not. The answers I've seen is that this `ConnectionHandler.run()` method is responsible for marshalling/unmarshalling things, when here I get 100% CPU without any network traffic. I can only infer an active wait on the sockets but that sounds odd, especially with non-blocking `SocketChannel`...

Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That code is only used by RMI. Somewhere you have an RMI service. A Registry for example?

Comment: No, nothing like it. It's all pure NIO code.
I was able to track CPU use down to the `select(int timeout)` I'm using, which returns `0` immediately, no matter what the timeout is! I'll develop that point in my upcoming edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tracked CPU use down to `select(int timeout)` which returns 0 immediately, regardless of the `timeout` value. My understanding of this function was it would block until a selected operation pops up, or timeout is reached (as said in the Javadoc).

However, I found out [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204186/java-nio-select-returns-without-selected-keys-why) showing the same problem: `OP_CONNECT` operation **has to be cancelled** once connection is accepted.

Many thanks to @Alexander, and @EJP for clarification about the `OP_WRITE`/`OP_CONNECT` similarities.

Regarding tge RMI part, it was probably due to Eclipse run configurations.